# Is there a way to activate a div by typing in a series of letters on the keyboard?

Tags: jquery, keypress

I want to insert a surprise "easter egg" on my website for my girlfriend. Basically, I want it so that if I type in the letters "K, I, M" in that order, a div activates on my site. Is this possible? Are there any tutorials that may explain this or get me started? Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would say that your question don't show much research effort, you can probably try something and edit your question to show us what you tried and eventually, doesn't work

Comment: Ah, my fault. Sorry about that. I did read up on jQuery's `.keypress` function but being a beginner in JS, it was a little difficult to understand how to do multiple keys. Thanks for explaining why I got the down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I've updated this after looking at ManseUK's updated fiddle (thanks ManseUK!), note that the code now checks for the reverse of KIM (MIK) before showing the easter egg. The easter egg will still be shown after the user types 'KIM' though

Something like this should put you on the right path -

```
<div id="easterEgg" style="display:none">Easter Egg!</div>

var test = '';
$("body").keyup(function(event)
{ 
    var c= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    test = c + test ;
    if (test.length > 2) test = test.substr(0,3) 
    if(test == 'MIK') $("#easterEgg").show();
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jRSEu/1/

Comment: Updated to that it accepts `KIM` after any amount of other key presses -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/j8RPW/1/

Comment: You guys are awesome. Unbelievable. Thank you so much! ipr101 - Just wondering but what is the relevance of checking for the reverse of KIM?

Comment: If I want to add a hide button (esc for example), would I need to add another if statement after the last one and use `.hide`?

Comment: I just realized this doesn't work in Firefox because typing any key brings up the quick find box. I suppose there isn't a way to disable that quick find on user's browsers? haha

Comment: If you add `if (event.keyCode == 27) $("#easterEgg").hide();` at the top of the function that should do the hide for you. Not sure about the Firefox thing.

Answer (score 2):

Heres another way of doing it

http://jsfiddle.net/8DtKp/6/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Jquery's change event handler. Try this

```
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="" />
</form>
<div id="easterEgg" style="display:none">Easter Egg!</div>

<script>
    $("target").change(function () {
        if( $("#target").val() === 'KIM'){
           $("#easterEgg").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#easterEgg").hide();
        }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. `target` and `easterEgg` aren't valid selectors and `$() === 'string'` is never true (did you mean `.val()`?). Furthermore I think the OP wants that you can just type the letters anywhere on the page, not in a specific input field.